# Time complexity of python sorted method inside a loop

Tags: python, time-complexity

```
def findEquals(words, word):
    wordCounts = sorted(Counter(word).values())
    equals = []

    for word in words:
        wordsCounts = sorted(Counter(word).values())
        if wordCounts == wordsCounts:
            equals.append(word)

    return equals
```

So I have this loop inside my code where words is a list of words. For each word in the list, I store the frequency of letters in a Counter as values which is then sorted using the method sorted(). I know that sorted() has a worst time complexity of O(nlog(n)). Am I right to say that the worst time complexity of the whole code is O(n^2 log(n)) since sorted() is used inside a for loop?

Comment: Your code is a little confusing to me. `sorted(Counter(word).values())` is going to create a `Counter` of letters and monotonically increasingly sorted by frequency? Then for each word, you're checking if the letter frequencies are the same? You don't need to sort.

Comment: Indeed. What does `findEquals` do? Why do you shadow the `word` variable?

Comment: I was asked to return all words inside a list of words where the frequency of letters correspond to the frequency of letters of an input word.

Comment: for example, daddy is equal to mummy, dddya and babdb.

Comment: @erip: Your analysis was almost correct. Complexity is indeed `O(m*n)`, you'd just need to modifiy a few things.

Comment: You really need to say what you mean with "n".

Answer (score 4):

> Am I right to say that the worst time complexity of the whole code is O(n^2 log(n)) since sorted() is used inside a for loop?

Not necessarily. It's true that a for loop is O(N), and that `sorted` is O(N log N), but the "N"s in those expressions refer to different values. The N in O(N) refers to the length of `words`, and the N in O(N log N) refers to the length of `word`.

It would only be correct to say that the total complexity of the algorithm is O(N^2 log N), if the average length of each `word` string is equal to the length of the `words` list. For instance, if `words` contained five words, each having five letters. But it is unlikely that this is the case. A more general conclusion to make might be that the algorithm is O(m * n log n), with m corresponding to the size of `words`, and n corresponding to the average size of a word.

Comment: Almost. Note that the sort isn't applied on the string but on `Counter.values`. Assuming a finite number of characters (e.g. ASCII), sorting operation is `O(1)`.

Comment: Yeah, there are a number of reasonable assumptions you can make about the input that simplifies analysis. If you assume that `words` is a list of ascii character sequences of arbitrary length, then `sorted` is O(1) and `Counter` is O(N). If you assume that `words` is composed of English words, and that there is a constant upper bound on the size of English words, then both `sorted` and `Counter` are O(1), and the whole algorithm becomes just O(m).

Answer (score 0):

The asymptotic analysis here will be a little weird because as you've written it, it's actually a function of three inputs: the haystack, the length of each word in the haystack, and the needle.

To make it more simple, you can cache the sorted values of the needle: these are static (and this operation will be overwhelmed by the iteration through the haystack).

I've also simplified the code to use filtering, which will abstract out the loop iteration. This won't have a theoretical impact on the performance of the algorithm, but returning an iterator will yield lazy results, which might improve real performance.

Because the frequencies will be integers, they can be sorted in [`O(n)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) with respect to the number of frequencies.

Thus, for every element in the haystack, you'll sort and compare with the needle's frequency. This will be `O(n*m)` where `n` is the size of haystack and `m` is the size of each element in haystack.

Therefore, your code can be simplified:

```
def find_same_frequency_distribution(haystack, needle):
    needle_counts = sorted(Counter(needle).values())
    return filter(lambda x: sorted(Counter(x).values()) == needle_counts, haystack)
```

```
>>> def find_same_frequency_distribution(haystack, needle):
...     needle_counts = sorted(Counter(needle).values())
...     return filter(lambda x: sorted(Counter(x).values()) == needle_counts, haystack)
...
>>> li = ["daddy", "mummy", "dddya", "foosa"]
>>> for e in find_same_frequency_distribution(li, "babdb"):
...     print(e)
...
daddy
mummy
dddya
```

Comment: OP doesn't check if dictionaries are equal, only if their `values` are equal : `'abcc'` and `'test'` are considered equals for example. Or `jello` and `hello`.